# EF Core Migrations in Separate Project - Issues

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I am not successful in adding ef core migrations in a separate project. I have provided the project structure at the end.

The DbContext class and the migrations are in separate projects such that the former is a class library and the migrations project is a console application. I added a reference to the DbContext project in the migrations project however, I am getting errors while running migration commands

\EF.BlogsDb.Migrations > dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project EF.BlogsDb.Migrations.csproj

No DbContext was found in assembly 'EF.BlogsDb.Migrations'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

I followed advise from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects) but I am not sure of the following.

In which project should i add these lines? is it the migrations project or my web project or the DbContext project?

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Migrations"));
```

Why should i Add a reference to the migrations assembly from the startup assembly?

From which location/folder/project should i run this command?

```
dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration --project MyApp.Migrations
```

I can share the source code if you can tell me how to do that.

Thanks in advance for the clarifications one might provide!

Here is my project structure looks like:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Looks like someone has answered the questions here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10806

Answer (score 23):

The issue is solved using the following command.

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../Project.Api/ migrations add InitialModel
```

- Here I am using separate folder for the api and the EF.
- Run the above command from the EF project folder
- Start up project means referred to the api