# Migrations in netcore 3.1 not working in a different project using MigrationsAssembly

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to add a migration in another project and I am literally getting white hair here trying different solutions found everywhere and none work, I just don't understand why isn't working.

I have this in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            c => c.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext"), 
            opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly("DatabaseContext.Migrations")));
```

I did check [this](https://github.com/bricelam/Sample-SplitMigrations), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912430/unable-to-retrieve-project-metadata-ensure-its-an-msbuild-based-net-core-proj), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509470/ef-core-migrations-in-separate-project-issues) and I think a few others, I don't know whats wrong.

For my solution structure is the following:

```
Shop (former empty solution)
1. DatabaseSchema (folder with empty spaces)
DatabaseContext (project with the migrations folder inside)
..
bunch of other stuff
..
ShopApi (here I have that code above in Startup.cs)
```

I tried:

dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration -s ../ShopAPI
dotnet ef migrations script --project DatabaseContext --startup-project ../ShopAPI

It simply says there is no project found, I don't understand whats wrong with the path, I go one folder up and the project is right there. As it gets extremely annoying and on my nerves I tried all combinations of paths and still not finding anything.

The path is like this:

```
Shop (Solution) -> 1. DatabaseSchema (Folder) -> DatabaseContext/Migrations
                -> ShopAPI (is where I have my Startup.cs)
```

What I don't understand here?

Answer (score 0):

Yea ok, I solved this after all
I used this command instead

```
Add-Migration Subcategory_Entity_Added -StartupProject ShopAPI
```

On Package manager console I set up the migration parent project.

And I removed MigrationsAssembly portion because the command above gave a different error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DatabaseContext.Migrations, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I guess it read the path as.. looking for a specific file because of the '.', I am not sure, I removed everything and tried it.