# Database.Migrate() .net6 not launch migrations

Tags: ef-core-6.0

I am trying to run the migrations automatically with net6

In program.cs

```
     using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiDbContext>();

            var pendingMigrations = db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
            var migrations = db.Database.GetMigrations();

            var items = db.Items.ToList();

            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

Values:

```
pendingMigrations = 0
migrations = 0 
items = nº elements in db, is correct
```

ApoDbcontext can access to db, but does not find unlaunched migrations

I can launch migrations in powershell, and run ok

Project (DDD layers):

```
|- Solution 
  |- Api 
     |- Program.cs
  |- Aplication
  |- Domain
  |- Infrastructure 
     |- Migrations (folder)
     |- ApiDbContext.cs
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../Project.Api/ migrations add InitialModel
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201822/4907049

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of why migrations aren't being applied with code. Here you are doing it manually in the terminal.